# Print multiple row outputs in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting, printing

Suppose

```
A='First'
B='Random'
C='Degree'
D='Largest'

A='Second'
B='Odd'
C='Inclined'
D='Maximum'

A='Third'
B='Even'
C='Steep'
D='Smallest'

A='Fourth'
B='Prime'
C='Gradient'
D='Minimum'

c = ['Group', 'Number', 'Angle', 'Max value']

df = pd.DataFrame([[A, B, C, D]], columns=c)
print (df)

#to csv
df.to_csv('Output.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Actual Output:

It is showing only the last output, instead of each and every value. Like this if there are N values, the csv  must store all the N values one below each other

```
Group  Number Angle    Max Value 
Fourth Prime  Gradient Minimum
```

Expected Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: you need to append data to data frame in loop and then save it as csv

Comment: You are overwriting your variables `A, B, C, D` everytime.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi - Could you suggest any method to append this data to the data frame and then show it in csv.

Comment: @Akshay K. first you need to set you data as list or dictionary as is show below, then you see this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be following this procedure:

First make a list of all columns, like this:

```
A = ['First', 'Random', 'Degree', 'Largest']
B = ['Second', 'Odd', 'Inclined', 'Maximum']
C = ['Third', 'Even', 'Steep', 'Smallest']
D = ['Fourth', 'Prime', 'Gradient', 'Minimum']
```

And then

```
c = ['Group', 'Number', 'Angle', 'Max value']
df = pd.DataFrame([A, B, C, D], columns=c)
print (df)

#to csv
df.to_csv('Output.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Output:

```
    Group  Number     Angle Max value
0   First  Random    Degree   Largest
1  Second     Odd  Inclined   Maximum
2   Third    Even     Steep  Smallest
3  Fourth   Prime  Gradient   Minimum
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your `A B C D` variables each time you re-define them. You should add them to a nested list or use a loop:

```
data = [
    ['First', 'Random', 'Degree', 'Largest'],
    ['Second', 'Odd', 'Inclined', 'Maximum'],
    ['Third', 'Even', 'Steep', 'Smallest'],
    ['Fourth', 'Prime', 'Gradient', 'Minimum']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=c)
```

Or....

```
A = ['First', 'Random', 'Degree', 'Largest']
B = ['Second', 'Odd', 'Inclined', 'Maximum']
C = ['Third', 'Even', 'Steep', 'Smallest']
D = ['Fourth', 'Prime', 'Gradient', 'Minimum']

df = pd.DataFrame([A, B, C, D], columns=c]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can go with the following code,

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['First', 'Random', 'Degree', 'Largest'],
    ['Second', 'Odd', 'Inclined', 'Maximum'],
    ['Third', 'Even', 'Steep', 'Smallest'],
    ['Fourth', 'Prime', 'Gradient', 'Minimum']
]


c = ['Group', 'Number', 'Angle', 'Max value']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=c)
print (df)

df.to_csv('Output.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

and the output is

[image]

Also the CSV file you get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your variables `A, B, C, D` everytime, so in the end in contains only the values of your last iteration.

The construction of your variables is bit counter intuitive, but the following will work in your case:

```
A = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth']
B = ['Random', 'Odd', 'Even', 'Prime']
C = ['Degree', 'Inclined', 'Steep', 'Gradient']
D = ['Largest', 'Maximum', 'Smallest', 'Minimum']

c = ['Group', 'Number', 'Angle', 'Max value']

df = pd.DataFrame(data =[A, B, C, D])

df = df.T
df.columns = c
print (df)

#to csv
df.to_csv('Output.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

---

```
    Group  Number     Angle Max value
0   First  Random    Degree   Largest
1  Second     Odd  Inclined   Maximum
2   Third    Even     Steep  Smallest
3  Fourth   Prime  Gradient   Minimum
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it is simple and easy

```
dictionary = {'Group':['First','Second','Third','Fourth'],
'Number' :['Random','Odd','Even','Prime'],
'Angle':['Degree','Inclined','Steep','Gradient'],
'Max value' :['Largest','Maximum','Smallest','Minimum']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
print (df)
#to csv
df.to_csv('Output.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```